# Not able to enable a button after it is disabled in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have just started learning java swing and I have been trying to create a simple game. The game is similar to minesweeper. A window with a matrix of bottons with just 1 mine. On clicking a button, if it's not a mine, i disable the button and display green color, and if it's a mine i disable the button and display red color. I have displayed the color by setting the button background to the required color. I have done the implementation so far just fine. 
Next i added a reset button, on clicking which i renable all buttons by using : setEnabled(true).

But for some reason, the button is not getting enabled. I have confirmed that the program flow reaches the code for enabling the button, but i'm not able to find the reason why it is not working.

Here is a test program i wrote with a reset button and 1 button. Same issue. Can anyone point out what I maybe doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Test implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mine");
    JButton buttons = new JButton();
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    Container grid = new Container();   

    public Test(){

        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(reset, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        reset.addActionListener(this);

        buttons = new JButton();
        buttons.addActionListener(this);    

        frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Test();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource().equals(reset))
            buttons.setEnabled(true);

        else{
            if(event.getSource()==buttons){
                buttons.setBackground(Color.RED);
                buttons.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just an advice: you should make your frame visible *after* adding all your components to its content pane. Instead of setting the frame's size exlicitely, call `pack()` method right before making it visible.

Comment: It does get enabled. You just never reset the background color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it's getting enabled when you click reset, all you forgot to do was reset the color:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource().equals(reset)){
        buttons.setEnabled(true);
        buttons.setBackground(null);
    }else{
        if(event.getSource()==buttons){
            System.out.println("xxx");
            buttons.setBackground(Color.RED);
            buttons.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yup, that was exactly my issue. thanks a lot. its working fine now.